# Mouse and keyboard not working after upgrading to 11.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10, neither my keyboard nor my mouse work anymore.

The keyboard works during the boot process, but stops working as soon as the login screen appears. I'm stuck there because without a mouse or a keyboard I can't login or start a shell.

If I hit ESC during startup to make the grub manager appear, the manager appears, but the keyboard won't work anymore.

Mouse: Logitech RX 250,

Keyboard: Cherry RS 6000

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer this question as there is not a lot of information in your post, a better way would be to go into the forums and search there or post some more of your logs there. For example a recently started thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11446690
also you should try and unplug, wait and replug your keyboard to see if this helps.
This is not a solution but might be a way to get it work until you find out more. You should really find the appropriate logs to post for someone who has a clue about this.

An alternative way is to post a bug report or search the bug reports of ubuntu for workarounds.
You would find: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/807306
which shows something that might be relevant to your problem and is quite a good bugreport I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom and in my case it resulted from keyboard being locked with dialog of opening private key database - only this dialog was able to use keyboard and it disabled all other windows from using keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Continuation of my answer above (I was not allowed to post more than two links...)
It is important that we learn how to pose the right question in the right place. Maybe start looking here: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html on how to do this.

This brings the whole community project forward by providing relevant information in the right place. If a few people do this the right way then others can find out the way to fix the problem and it will be committed and fixed in the software project. after a short time a simple update/upgrade will be enough to fix the problem on your computer.

The best place to track this are the bug reports on launchpad as I have posted above. As they also indicate when a bug is fixed or how it can be fixed.